# ExtJS combo-box value field

Tags: extjs, combobox

I'm using ExtJS in CodeIgniter (a PHP framework)

I want to store the `valueField` of a `combobox` in a database. I set `displayField:'name', valueField:'id'` for the combobox, but when i used `$this->input->post(combofield name);` it is returning the `displayField` instead.

How am I able to get the `valueField`?

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the hiddeName property or else it will send the displayField value not the valueField. Make sure you name it differently than the displayField.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of **`PHP`**; but i guess you want to post the data as of **`valueField`** but **`displayField`** is being posted instead. If yes, then i would request you to check the **`name`** property and **`id`** property as well with anyother **form fields for it's uniquness**.

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your properties:

```
    displayField:'state',
    valueField: 'id', 
    hiddenName: "id",
```